# Repository item lookUpEdit resets after losing focus

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have this problem for days and can't find solution for it. I tried all possible solutions i found on internet, but seems like none suits this one. 
Thing is that i added repository item to gridControls (i added it through designer, not through code). Then, in code i added data source to that repository lookUpEdit and i have items in dropDown in that column. But when i select item in repository and click on other cell, Selected item in repository is cleared and repository shows null value again... 
Any ideas what i did wrong ?

EDIT:
Also, when i click on any cell in my grid, i have delay of second or two, and after that delay clicked cell is focused... Any solutions for all of this?

EDIT: 
Don't know what code to show You, because I did all in devExpress designer. Here is part of the code where I set data source to repository item, and i will give You code from designer of that repository item.

```
private void ConfigureRepositoryItems()
    {
        BetService.SportManagerClient dbSportManager = new BetService.SportManagerClient();

        BetService.BLOddsControlSettings[] oddsControlSettings = dbSportManager.GetOddsControlSettings("", "");


        repositoryOddsControlSettings1.DataSource = oddsControlSettings;

    }
```

And here is code from designer:

```
// 
        // repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1
        // 
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.AutoHeight = false;
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] {
        new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)});
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo[] {
        new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("ID", "ID", 20, DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.None, "", false, DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Default),
        new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Name", "Name")});
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.Name = "repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1";
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.NullText = "Select Settings";
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.PopupSizeable = false;
        this.repositoryOddsCalculationSettings1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: What is the data type for the field to which the LookUpEdit is assigned to? Did you set the GridColumn's FieldName property?

Comment: @Brandon - I made 2 columns in my LookUpEdit repository. "ID" and "Name". "Name" column shows string type of data. My gridControl is bounded to dataSource, but my column is not, so in designer i left "fieldName" property empty and my "Unbound type" property i set to "String".

Comment: I had a similar issue. The reason was wrong value member (I used "ID" instead of "Id").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters check whether the column name in your `Grid` datasource and the column in your grid control match. The match is case sensitive so `name` and `Name` are not same and hence can cause this issue. Secondly make sure the `Grid` datasource column datatype matches the value type of the `LookUpEdit`. If the `LookupEdit` is returning `int` and the `Grid` datasource column datatype is `string`, this alone can cause lots of headaches.

Comment: Mine was because the class i was using was using fields `public int Number;` instead of properties `public int Number { get; set; }`